# Ubuntu 18.04 - Why is Xorg using so much memory after a few hours?

Tags: 18.04, xorg

After a few hours of work my Shared and buff/cache memory is going to the roof and I have no idea why

```
murilo@murilo-Inspiron-7586:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.8G        5.7G        5.9G        6.9G        6.4G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

I tried running those following [this](https://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/) which didn't help:

```
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Some more information with `ipcs --human`:

```
murilo@murilo-Inspiron-7586:~$ ipcs --human

------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      size         messages    

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      size       nattch     status      
0x00000000 37683200   murilo     600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 393218     murilo     600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 425987     murilo     600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 37027844   murilo     600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 753670     murilo     600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 37486599   murilo     600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 29163536   murilo     600          512K     2          dest         

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems
```

Using `top`

```
top - 17:48:36 up  8:31,  1 user,  load average: 0.30, 0.63, 0.91
Tasks: 331 total,   1 running, 262 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.8 us,  0.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.0 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16106352 total,  6249628 free,  3129784 used,  6726940 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  6462552 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                  
 7798 murilo    20   0 5066228 4.434g 4.408g S   3.9 28.9  22:03.44 Xorg                                                                                                                                     
 7995 murilo    20   0 4047572 311012  47352 S  10.2  1.9  22:30.53 gnome-shell                                                                                                                              
 8186 murilo    20   0 1439744 301692   9908 S   0.0  1.9   0:35.47 gsd-color                                                                                                                                
 8170 murilo    20   0  790348 297284   7760 S   0.0  1.8   0:07.50 gsd-wacom                                                                                                                                
 8136 murilo    20   0 1149152 297160   7220 S   0.0  1.8   0:08.60 gsd-power                                                                                                                                
19276 murilo    20   0 1235076 257776 145700 S   0.7  1.6   1:04.74 chrome                                                                                                                                   
 1230 mysql     20   0 1679796 207752      0 S   0.0  1.3   0:33.85 mysqld                                                                                                                                   
 8496 murilo    20   0 1215920 148452  10560 S   0.0  0.9   0:08.02 gnome-software                                                                                                                           
21307 murilo    20   0  852072 147412  79140 S   3.3  0.9   0:09.69 chrome                                                                                                                                   
19637 murilo    20   0  823724 142936  80548 S   0.0  0.9   0:18.32 chrome                                                                                                                                   
21098 murilo    20   0  808924 136076  80172 S   0.0  0.8   0:35.22 chrome                                                                                                                                   
21290 murilo    20   0  782812 126160  77212 S   0.0  0.8   0:05.29 chrome                                                                                                                                   
20446 murilo    20   0  779960 121392  79456 S   0.0  0.8   0:04.87 chrome
```

I closed pretty much all my processes and my computer is still using half its memory. Crazy.

Comment: I wouldn't count buffers and cached as used memory. Linux is simply taking advantage of unneeded RAM to speed up operations. Linux doesn't need that RAM and gives it back to applications if needed at the cost of slower operations.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yeah I know, my problem is more with the shared memory. As you can see I have a 16gb RAM and after a few hours of work my computer freezes. Those screenshots were taken after I closed pretty much everything, re-opened chrome so I could post here and that was it. The only opened programs were the shell and chrome.

Comment: I seem to experience the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. As time goes on, the slowdown becomes progressively worse, until desktop env is basically unusably slow. X does not seem to release memory. Only work-a-round  I have found to date is to either log out/in, or `/etc/init.d/lightdm restart` (effectively the same thing). Only marginally better than sys restart. Might be worth mentioning I am using proprietary Nvidia drivers for graphics card.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, `top` shows Xorg taking 4.4G of residential memory. IMO it is not peanuts.

Comment: Hi! Have you found the cause of your issues? Solved? Cheers.